# Populating multiple webpage output with one global database query?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can one make one global database query (with PHP) and then use all the output (multiple rows) on various places on a webpage?

I read that javascripts can be called for each specific field on a webpage that needs data, but this is inefficient with regards to performance.

The webpage would contact a sort of table-of-contents with version numbers next to each of them.  Those version numbers are stored inside the database and calling the database 20 times for the 20 different fields would be inefficient.

Any suggestions on how to run say a PHP query globally when the page loads and then later in the page use the different output at different locations on the page?

## QUESTION UPDATE WITH EXAMPLE OF DESIRED OUTPUT:

The webpage should show the following output:

```
Document Name            Document Version

DEPT A DOCS:
Doc ABC                    1.2
- Description of doc
Doc another doc            2.3
- Description of doc

DEPT B DOCS:
Yet another doc            0.9
- Description of doc
Doc XYZ                    3.0
- Description of doc
```

Each of the documents have its own version associated with it.  Each document has its own table inside the database with its associated version and this can be queried from a Postgres function or View.  I wish to query this function or view only once and then display the results in a sort of 'table-of-contents' style (or table sort of view) on the webpage.

Thank you

P.S. This is my first post here.

Answer (score 0):

Make the query in a separate PHP page that is included in all the pages you want to use the information on.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of your page make one database query to get data for all versions.

Using PHP split it into associative array having version number as key.

Then during in different section of your page just apply to that array with version number. output the data the way you need. and it will be the data of this version

Comment: In the lower part of the page, where the HTML is used to structure the elements and write the 'text' and also the version numbers output, how do I reference those previously PHP generated output?

Do I open a new php tag in the middle of the HTML code and then access those global (?) variables or javascript?  I am unsure as to how to reference data that was generated at the top of the page from another script in the middle of the HTML document.

Comment: hm... now I'm not sure I follow... So, you have some kind table of content on top of the page: list of versions. When user clicks on a version from the list, you want to show subrecords of that version? And all that should be pre-loaded? Look, may be you can show the sample of what you wantl or be more specific

Comment: I have updated my question above with an example of the desired output.  The idea is to only query the database once, which would return multiple rows (docs and their version numbers) and then later in the HTML page, show those different document names with their associated version numbers next to them.  Since the output might not be a simple matrix-style table layout, but separated with text and descriptions, I need to access those previously returned database results one at a time from different places on the web-page.  Thanks for any guidance.